# iOS: How do I swap landscape orientation Xs and Ys

Tags: ios, ios5

My app is going to be landscape only. I am have major problems with width, height, x, and y variables. Is there a way to swap all width, height, x, and y values so I don't have to reverse all the coordinates in my app? (I.e. (x,y) has to become (y,x) and something.width has to be something.height.)

Here is a concrete example of my problems:

```
-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:unitArea];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.view.frame, touchPoint))
    {
        NSLog(@"released in area");
    }
}
```

This isn't working in landscape... It is using the wrong coordinates, and in some places, it will output "released in area", but not in the actual area that the view is located.

```
unitArea bounds are <UIView: 0x6a52420; frame = (20 0; 300 480); transform = [0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0]; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x6a524a0>>
```

This is showing as my view's bounds when it should be (0 20; 480 300).

Edit, more information:

Here is my (premade) orientation method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

And in the Project summary my "Supported Device Orientations" are only set to landscape.

Comment: If your app is truly in landscape, then iOS handles the coordinate translation for you.

Comment: Updated to provide more information.

Comment: Shouldn't it be touch [locationInView:self.view]?

Comment: What is the view in CGRectContainsPoint(self.view.frame, touchPoint) line? is it view of your windows rootViewController?

Comment: I was using locationInView:unitArea because I'm checking for a touch only in that area. The view in CGRectContainsPoint() is the main view in a newly made view based application.

Comment: OK looking into it further, the width and height of the unitArea view is 300 wide and 480 high where, in the interface builder, it's 480 wide and 150 high

Comment: Found the bug! It turns out when using the assistant to create the IBOutlet, it sort of created a link, but it didn't... So I deleted the link and remade it, and it works now!

Answer (score 3):

In iOS window coordinates are always in portrait mode. So the frame of the view of your rootViewController will be always in portrait mode. Try to insert another view in to this view. The frame of the new view must change orientation confirms to device orientation.