# How can I move a sprite directly from the right to the left side of the screen?

Tags: objective-c, sprite

My aliens are generated at the bottom of the screen randomly along the X axis. They move diagonally to the top left corner of the screen.

I'd like to have them instead appear from the right side of the screen randomly along the Y axis and then move in a straight line from right to left.

How can I alter the following code to do that? I'm a novice here... please help if you can:

```
if (curTime > _nextAlienSpawn) 
{

    float randSecs = [self randomValueBetween:0 andValue:13];
    _nextAlienSpawn = randSecs + curTime;

    float randY = [self randomValueBetween:0 andValue:winSize.height];
    float randDuration = [self randomValueBetween:30 andValue:60];

    alien = [_aliens objectAtIndex:_nextAlien];
    _nextAlien++;
    if (_nextAlien >= _aliens.count) _nextAlien = 0;

    [alien stopAllActions];
    alien.position = ccp(winSize.width+alien.contentSize.width, randY);
    alien.visible = YES;
    [alien runAction:[CCSequence actions:
    [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:randDuration position:ccp(- winSize.width-alien.contentSize.width, -500)],

    [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(setInvisible:)],
                         nil]];

}
```

Comment: Looks like I made some progress by editing the following line: `alien.position = ccp(winSize.width+alien.contentSize.width, randY);`

Comment: I subtracted instead of added, and my aliens appear to be generating a bit higher on the screen than before.

Comment: should your second to last line be `ccp(- winSize.width-alien.contentSize.width, -500)` not `winSize.height`?

Comment: @NHDaly I do believe you're right on that. I still can't edit the Y value to get the aliens to appear higher up on the screen. They continue to generate interestingly about 30 pixels from the bottom of the screen and make their way to the top left. So, I figure, if they're being added just a hair north from the bottom of the screen, there's got to be a way to change the value to make them start higher.

Comment: I'm wondering if somehow you've got your x and y values swapped. I don't know a lot about what you're doing, so I can't say.. But `- winSize.height-alien.contentSize.width` would probably be pretty close to a hair north from the bottom, don't you think?  And then you say that they're randomizing in the X instead of the Y, well up there you're putting randY into the Y value, so i wonder if somehow they're swapped? Try just swapping the values and then let's see what happens?

Comment: OOOH! I wonder: Is your game in landscape mode? And if so, have you made a new view or are you working in window coordinates? Because window coordinates are always portrait, so x and y would be swapped if you're in landscape!!! Here's a relevant link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794301/ios-how-do-i-swap-landscape-orientation-xs-and-ys

Comment: that is totally the issue! haha

Comment: Great! I've added an answer below. I also edited the second-to-last line per my first comment here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your app is running in Landscape mode, but you are still using Window coordinates, which **always refer to portrait coordinates**. [This stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794301/ios-how-do-i-swap-landscape-orientation-xs-and-ys) addresses the issue you're having!

From that answer, it sounds like you need to create a new child view, and allow that view to rotate correctly, so that X and Y will be relative to the *view*, not to the window. Then, your code should work as you have it above!